# jQuery Validate Range for a select form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a registration form with jQuery [Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/min#value). One of the requirements is that the select field must select a persons minimum age (13).

How would i do that? I can figure out the minimum year but i can't figure out how jquery validate picks a range described here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/min#value

Form markup:

```
<form>
...
<select id="yearborn" name="yearborn">
<option value="" disabled="disabled">Choose an option</option>
<option value="1901" >1901</option>
<option value="1902" >1902</option>
<option value="1903" >1903</option>
...
<option value="2011" >2011</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Then the attempted jQuery form validation:

```
jQuery('#register-form')
      .validate({        
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();      
        },
        rules: {
          yearborn: {
            required: true,
            min: 13
          }
        }
    });
```

Any ideas? I looked over this thread but it's related to requiring input:

- [jQuery Validate Required Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select)
- [jQuery Validate (Date Range)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761185/jquery-validate-date-range) - Used a different field

Answer (score 0):

Why even give the user the option to choose an invalid year ?

If you can control the server-side that prints the select-box, just print the allowed years (this year - 13),

otherwise min should be a year, not an age ...

min 1998  == 2011-13 (this year - 13)

Comment: If i did it that way everyone that signs up by default can become a member. Rendering it pointless.

Comment: if values in <option> is year of birth, then the the min value in js-validation should be year of birth. Otherwise you need to calculate the age ?