# special datepicker for date range

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need urgently to make  a range datepicker for two dates :start date and end date.
Start date cannot be before date time now and end date cannot be before choosed start date.
Here is an example of what i want.Can somebody tell me  what to use to make this?

http://rezervari.hotelalpin.ro/

this is what i tried but is not working:

```
         </head>
       @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchFree", "Reservation", FormMethod.Get,new {id = "form" }))
     {                    

       <h7>Introduceti perioada Rezervarii</h7>
      <div class="editor-label">
       <label id="cautare" for="StartDate">Data Intrare:        </label>@(Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("StartDate").DateFormat("mm-dd-yy").MinDate(DateTime.Today).ShowButtonPanel(true).ChangeYear(true).ChangeMonth(true).NumberOfMonths(2))
        </div>
          <div class="editor-label">
         <label  id="cautare"  for="EndDate">Data Iesire:        </label>@(Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("EndDate").DateFormat("mm-dd-yy").MinDate(DateTime.Today).ShowButtonPanel(true).ChangeYear(true).ChangeMonth(true).NumberOfMonths(2))

         </div>

       <p>
       <input id="buton1" type="submit" value="Cauta camere libere" />
          </p>

  }
         <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
  $.validator.addMethod("EndDate", function (value, element) {
    var startDate = $('.StartDate').val();
    return Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(value);
     }
  , "* End date must be after start date");
 $('.form').validate();
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Did you even try to find one?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761185/jquery-validate-date-range) for tips on using jQuery Validate for this purpose.

Comment: @Blazemonger The question you're linking to is different from this one, in that this question involves 2 inputs for a start and end date, but the linked question involves a single input with an arbitrary date range constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jquery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range) has a date range option that you can use. You can set it up like this:

**HTML**:

```
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from"/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(function() {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });

    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you this what i was looking for. is there any posibility to make it readonly so that i cannot introduce data manualy(only by selcting from date picker.And any posibility to allow to date to change after i make change to "from" date because its working at the begin but after i choose from date again and go back to chose and date i cannot do this.

Comment: You can just make the textboxes readonly. In the onchange of the from textbox you can either clear out or set the to textbox to a day after the from date.

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to do that with a [JQuery date picker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)!

You can then use some Javascript/JQuery validation to alert the user if they enter a date outside the range you specify.

Comment: jQuery datepicker has setting to allow you to set a specific range for users to choose between.

Comment: Indeed Josh Mein! There is a tab on the right hand side of the link I gave to see an example where the date is restricted -> 'Restrict Date Range'.

Comment: See http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max -- however, this only applies to the datepicker calendar, and does NOT prevent the user from typing in an out-of-range date. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761185/jquery-validate-date-range) for suggestions on using jQuery Validate to require dates to be within a a given range.

Comment: So, either disable the user from putting input directly into the field, or validate the form values as an extra precaution on form submit using JQuery or JavaScript validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the range of selectable dates using the `minDate` and `maxDate` options of jQuery datepicker. See an example here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="tbStartDate" value="" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" id="tbEndDate" value="" disabled="disabled" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tbStartDate").datepicker({
            //minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1),  //use for Date time now
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: '/Content/Calendar.png',
            buttonText: 'Click here (date)',
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var $endDate = $('#tbStartDate').datepicker('getDate');
                $endDate.setDate($endDate.getDate() + 1);
                $('#tbEndDate').datepicker('setDate', $endDate).datepicker("option", 'minDate', $endDate);
            },
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                //$("#StartDate").val($("#tbStartDate").val());
            }
        });

        $("#tbEndDate").datepicker({
            //minDate: new Date($("#tbStartDate").datepicker('getDate')),
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: '/Content/Calendar.png',
            buttonText: 'Click here (date)',
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                $('#tbStartDate').datepicker("option", 'minDate', new Date($("#tbEndDate").datepicker('getDate')));
            },
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                //$("#EndDate").val($("#tbEndDate").val());
            }
        });

            var $endDate = $('#tbStartDate').datepicker('getDate');
            $endDate.setDate($endDate.getDate() + 1);
            $('#tbEndDate').datepicker('setDate', $endDate).datepicker("option", 'minDate', $endDate);              });
</script>
```